PowerShell の ActivePrinter 実行時にエラー: "ActivePrinter" の設定中に例外が発生しました: "HRESULT からの例外:0x800A03EC"
PowerShell のスクリプト内で後述の関数を使用すると以下のエラーになります。

エラー:
"ActivePrinter" の設定中に例外が発生しました: "HRESULT からの例外:0x800A03EC"

後述の関数はもともと ExportAsFixedFormat メソッドで PDF 出力するものでしたが(その際は意図した動作になっていました)、諸要件があり PrintOut に変更しました。
メモリリークを疑い、Excel プロセスをすべて削除した状態でもエラーは解消しませんでした。
コード上の問題はないように思い、プロンプトから以下のコマンドを実行したところ
同様のエラーが出力されました。

実行コマンド:
$excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Add()
$excelApp.Visible = $true
$excelApp.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF"

以上より、PowerShell 側の問題でもないように思えますが、PowerShell に明るくなくそもそも実行方法自体が間違っているのか判断ができません。次のステップへの糸口がなく、何かご助言いただければ幸いです。
現状のコード:
function Convert-ExcelToPDF {
    param (
        [string]$excelPath,
        [string[]]$sheetNames
    )

    # Start Excel APP
    $excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excelApp.Visible = $false
    $excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false
    
    try {
        # Open file
        $workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Open($excelPath)
        $pdfWorkbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Add()

        foreach ($sheetName in $sheetNames) {
            $sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item($sheetName)
            # Copy the specified sheet to the new workbook
            $sheet.Copy($pdfWorkbook.Sheets($pdfWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        }
        
        # Create PDF file path
        $pdfPath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($excelPath, "pdf")
        
        $excelApp.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
        # Save as PDF
        $pdfWorkbook.PrintOut($null, $null, $null, $null, "Microsoft Print to PDF", $null, $null, $pdfPath)
        Write-Host "Excel file converted to PDF: $pdfPath"

        # Close file
        $pdfWorkbook.Close($false)
        $workbook.Close($false)
    } finally {
        # Exit Excel APP
        $excelApp.Quit()
    }
}


エラーメッセージで検索してみると、主に Excel 関連のエラーとしてヒットするようです。これらも調べてみると何かヒントになるかもしれません。

試してみました。
下記のようになりました。
    PowerShell 7.4.5
PS > $excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
PS > $workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Add()
PS > $excelApp.Visible = $true
PS > $excelApp.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
OperationStopped: Application クラスの ActivePrinter プロパティを設定できません。
PS > $excelApp.Application.ActivePrinter
Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne01:
PS > $excelApp.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne01:"
PS >

port が必要なようです。
Application.ActivePrinter プロパティ (Excel) | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/excel.application.activeprinter
追記）2024 10/11 13:45
少し長いですがポートを取得する例です。
環境
Windows 11 Pro 24H2
PowerShell 7.4.5
######################
#  関数の定義
######################
##
# プリンター名にポート番号を付加する
##
function Get-MyPrinterOnPort {
  param($PrinterName)

  $portName = $null
  # レジストリの取得
  $keyPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PrinterPorts'
  # レジストリキーの存在チェック
  if (Test-Path $keyPath) {
    # レジストリキーの取得
    $regKey = Get-Item $keyPath
    # PrinterPortsからプリンターのポート情報を取得する
    # winspool,Ne01:,15,45
    $printerPort = $regKey.GetValue($PrinterName)
    if ($printerPort -ne $null) {
      # ポート情報を, で分割する
      $portinfos = $printerPort -split ","
      if ($portinfos.length -gt 2)
      {
        $portName = $portinfos[1]
        # 
        $PrinterName + " on " + $portName
      } else {
        Write-Host("【エラー】レジストリにポート名がありません ${PrinterName} [${printerPort}]")
      }
    } else {
      Write-Host("【エラー】レジストリにエントリーがありません ${keyPath} ${PrinterName}")
    }
  } else {
    Write-Host("【エラー】レジストリキーがありません ${keyPath}")
  }
}
######################
#  関数の定義 ここまで
######################

$printerOnPort = Get-MyPrinterOnPort('Microsoft Print to PDF')
$printerOnPort


ありがとうございます。仮想ポートまで明記したところ、こちらでも解消しました。
しかし、仮想ポートは(基本的に解放されることはないものの)動的に割り当てられる認識なので、そもそも PowerShell のコーディングでスクリプトの処理に PrintOut は向いていないのかもと考えました。

ポートを取得する例を追加しました。

全く別のアプローチで、Office 2007以降ではPDFに対応しています。具体的にはエクスポートメニューにPDFの作成があります。

これに対応するのは、Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormatメソッドになります。
$workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat("xlTypePDF", "ファイル名")

とできます。

ご提示いただいた ExportAsFixedFormat を当初は使用していたのですが、以下のように複数のシートを PDF 化したとき、ページサイズがずれる現象が発生したため PrintOut の採用を検討しています。
http://donboolacoo.blog92.fc2.com/blog-entry-2047.html
